# Material Md select not working in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

`md-select` not working in my code. I imported every css and js files needed for angular so dont say to import files properly. I'm building a web application. I'm almost done with that but on client side validation `<md-select>` not working.

```
<md-input-container class="md-block" style="margin-bottom: 0px;padding:2px;">
    <md-select name="gender" ng-model="gender" ng-required="true" >
    <label value="gender" style="padding-left: 13px">Gender</label>
        <md-option value="male">Male</md-option>
        <md-option value="female">Female</md-option>
        <md-option value="others">Others</md-option>
    </select>
    <div class="errors" ng-messages="form.gender.$error">
         <div ng-message="required">Please Select Your Gender</div>
     </div>
 </md-input-container>
```

It should work fine but for me it's not working it shows error but redirects to next page. So please someone solve my issue.

Comment: any error in console ?

Comment: no error has been displayed

Comment: <md-select name="gender" ng-model="gender" ng-required="true" >
                    <label value="gender" style="padding-left: 13px">Gender</label>
                    <md-option value="male">Male</md-option>
                    <md-option value="female">Female</md-option>
                    <md-option value="others">Others</md-option>
                </md-select>
                <div class="errors" ng-messages="form.gender.$error">
                  <div ng-message="required">Please Select Your Gender</div>
                </div>

Comment: this is my final code

Comment: Is this Angular 2.x or AngularJS 1.x question? Why tag both?

Comment: to get response from angular2 expert

Answer (score 1):

```
<body ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <md-select name="gender" ng-model="gender" ng-required="true">
    <label value="gender" style="padding-left: 13px">Gender</label>
    <md-option value="male">Male</md-option>
    <md-option value="female">Female</md-option>
    <md-option value="others">Others</md-option>
  </md-select>
  <div class="errors" ng-messages="form.gender.$error">
    <div ng-message="required">Please Select Your Gender</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

**[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/iCbuNuu7OVTmGAdsGLFS?p=preview)**

Comment: you are mixing both angular and bootstrap , go through the documentation https://material.angularjs.org/latest/layout/introduction

Comment: my problem is not with bootstrap and angular my problem is md-select  is not working on my code  . you got it man?

Comment: @dharmanraj that is the issue! your app is not at all angular material

Comment: check this demo and apply the same http://codepen.io/sajeetharan/pen/KNyObN

Answer (score 0):

md-select not validating anymore so use select in the md-input-container. i solved this issue by following the github angular issue page.